# Is there some kind of size limit when using range requests in Chromium browser?

Tags: javascript, rest, google-chrome, nginx

I use following code to make range request to some large model file on the server, and then display the model using Cesium:

```js
            const m = 1024 * 1024 * 3;
            Axios({
              url: option.url,
              method: 'head'
            }).then((res) => {
              const size = Number(res.headers['content-length']);
              const length = parseInt(size / m);
              const arr = []
              for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                  let start = i * m;
                  let end = (i == length - 1) ?  size - 1  : (i + 1) * m - 1;
                  arr.push(this.downloadRange(option.url, start, end, i))
              }
              Promise.all(arr).then(res => {
                const arrBufferList = res.sort(item => item.i - item.i).map(item => new Uint8Array(item.buffer));
                const allBuffer = this.concatenate(Uint8Array, arrBufferList);
                primitive = viewer.scene.primitives.add(
                  new Cesium.Model({
                    gltf: allBuffer,
                    show: true, // default
                    modelMatrix: modelMatrix,
                    scale: parseFloat(option.scale) || 1,
                  })
                );
              })
            })
```

The `downloadRange` method goes like this:

```js
downloadRange(url, start, end, i) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open("GET", url, true);
        req.setRequestHeader("range", `bytes=${start}-${end}`);
        req.responseType = "blob";
        req.onload = function (oEvent) {
          req.response.arrayBuffer().then((res) => {
            resolve({
              i,
              buffer: res,
            });
          });
        };
        req.send();
      });
    }
```

When the `m`(range size) is smaller than about 1024*1024*6 (about 6mb), the request would be returned successfully, however when `m` is larger than that, the browser would say `GET <url> net::ERR_FAILED 206 (Partial Content)` and the request would fail. When I use postman to test the service it would return normally with a much larger size(30mb) so there should be no problem on the server side. I wonder what would cause this? Is there some kind of limit on chromium? Is there any way to get around it? Thanks for any reply in advance.

This would happen both on Chrome and Edge, and maybe other browsers.

Comment: `Promise.all(arr)`  You do know this will try to execute all those ranges in parallel?.   So you might find it's not a limit on range, but connection count, and that indeed does have limits..

Comment: On a side note, what benefit of using ranges do you believe this is giving you?.  The main reason for range requests is to have the ability to resume downloads, nothing in your code above appears to do any of that, so just downloading the whole blob in one go is going to be just / if not more efficient.

Comment: I was trying to divide it into several smaller parts and download different parts in parallel, then assemble it back together in `Promise.all` so it might save some time. I'm aware that divide it into very small parts it would be slow, and I would like to try to divide it into bigger parts. If this is proven to be less efficient compared to just download it in one go I would revert to that. However I don't think it is relevent to connection count, since dividing the blob into smaller parts(more connection) will work but bigger parts won't

Comment: UPDATE: It would work in incognito mode so it might be a cache problem? Also, the performance of dividing it into bigger batches is slightly faster than requesting all of it in one go, there are improvements, but not much.